# Include a directory recursively for vim autocompletion

Tags: vim

I use vim from the base directory of my source code. I would like to have autocomplete consider every word of every file in this directory (and subdirectories) when editing a single file.

Comment: Thanks guys, the set complete= and argadd both worked.  Didn't try Exuberant Ctags due to lack of Scala support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
:argadd **/*
```

This will recursively load all files into buffers, and the completion will consider them. Beware that this will load all files, including files you might not want to add, such as binary files or files in CVS directories. A more fine-grained glob such as the one below might be a good idea.

```
:argadd **/*.cpp
```

Answer (score 8):

Completion is controlled by the `'complete'` option. With the `k` flag, you can have Vim scan files. The `**` wildcard stands for a recursive descent into subdirectories. Voila:

```
:set complete=k**/*
```

When you want to keep the other default locations (other buffers, included files, etc.), use `:set complete+=` to add to it.

---

Alternatively, as this can be too slow for a default, you can use the 'dictionary' option and use Ctrl-X Ctrl-K completion:

```
:set dictionary=**/*
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a much better approach is to generate a tags file in your directory system using [Exuberant CTags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/).

For starters, build your `tags` file in the root of your source with:

> ctags -R .

This may find more than you like, but you can tune it with further command line options.

Set your `tags` option to refer to this file ("tags" is the default name), or use `set tags=./tags;/` to search up your directory tree to the first tags file found.  See `:help file-searching` to understand the `;/` syntax for upward search.

Finally, make sure that 't' is in your complete option.  It's there by default, but check with `set complete?`.  If it's not there, `set complete+=t` will put it there.

I personally remove 'i' and 'd' from my `'complete'` option, because the disk access is annoying, even though typing CTRL_Y (yes, accept completion) or CTRL_N (no, reject completion) or continuing normal typing will stop the search.  If all the included files are in your tags file, you'll find the completion instantly.